# SQL Server - break down a payment correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is the problem I am having

**Example:**

- Total Value: £1550.00
- Monthly Payments 12

This calculates at 129.16666666666666667, however you wouldn't show a money value like this, it would display as £129.17, which equals £1550.04, which is wrong

**Question**

Is it possible to remove the float/decimal value from 11 of the 12 installments , and only display it in the first or final payment?

**Example Result**

```
    PaymentNumber         Value
          1              £129.00 
          2              £129.00 
          3              £129.00 
          4              £129.00 
          5              £129.00 
          6              £129.00 
          7              £129.00 
          8              £129.00 
          9              £129.00 
         10              £129.00 
         11              £129.00 
         12              £131.00
```

thanks for any help, and any suggestions of another way I could do this would be very grateful..

I have included the code for a table i am using to test this... and also added in the data below. for now using an update statement will be acceptable and i will try to make the code more efficient at a later date. I do have a procedure running that inserts the monthly breakdowns programmatically.

**Table info I am using**

```
CREATE TABLE CustomerFinance (CustomerFinanceID int identity (1,1) not null,
TotalValueOwed decimal(12,4), --1550.00
LengthOfContract int) --LENGTGH IN MONTHS, i.e. 12

CREATE TABLE CustomerFinanceLine (CustomerFinanceLineID int identity (1,1) not null,
CustomerFinanceID int, --FOREIGN KEY LINK
PaymentNumber int, --1, 2, 3 AND SO ON
PaymentValue decimal(12,4)) --THE MONTHLY BREAKDOWN COSTS

--KEYS
alter table CustomerFinance add constraint CustomerFinanceID_PK PRIMARY KEY (CustomerFinanceID)
alter table CustomerFinanceLine add constraint CustomerFinanceLineID_PK PRIMARY KEY (CustomerFinanceLineID)
alter table CustomerFinanceLine add constraint CustomerFinanceID_FK FOREIGN KEY (CustomerFinanceID) REFERENCES CustomerFinance(CustomerFinanceID)

--PaymentNumber COUNTER (RUNS IN A PROCEDURE)
CREATE PROCEDURE FinanceCounter AS
;WITH MyCTE AS
(
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerFinanceID ORDER BY CustomerFinanceLineID) AS NewVariation
    FROM   CustomerFinanceLine
)
UPDATE MyCTE 
SET    PaymentNumber = NewVariation
WHERE PaymentNumber IS NULL
```

**Data**

```
--inserted PaymentValue as null for now, ideally i will
-- have a procedure to do this and insert the breakdowns programmatically
--for now an update statement will do fine unless its easier to insert it
INSERT INTO CustomerFinance VALUES (1550.00, 12)

INSERT INTO CustomerFinanceLine VALUES (1, 1, NULL)
INSERT INTO CustomerFinanceLine VALUES (1, 2, NULL)
INSERT INTO CustomerFinanceLine VALUES (1, 3, NULL)
INSERT INTO CustomerFinanceLine VALUES (1, 4, NULL)
INSERT INTO CustomerFinanceLine VALUES (1, 5, NULL)
INSERT INTO CustomerFinanceLine VALUES (1, 6, NULL)
INSERT INTO CustomerFinanceLine VALUES (1, 7, NULL)
INSERT INTO CustomerFinanceLine VALUES (1, 8, NULL)
INSERT INTO CustomerFinanceLine VALUES (1, 9, NULL)
INSERT INTO CustomerFinanceLine VALUES (1, 10, NULL)
INSERT INTO CustomerFinanceLine VALUES (1, 11, NULL)
INSERT INTO CustomerFinanceLine VALUES (1, 12, NULL)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to do something like

```
WITH T(PaymentNumber) AS
(
SELECT 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 4 UNION ALL
SELECT 5 UNION ALL
SELECT 6 UNION ALL
SELECT 7 UNION ALL
SELECT 8 UNION ALL
SELECT 9 UNION ALL
SELECT 10 UNION ALL
SELECT 11 UNION ALL
SELECT 12
)
SELECT CASE WHEN PaymentNumber < 12 THEN FLOOR(1550.00/12)
          WHEN PaymentNumber = 12 THEN 1550.00 - 11*FLOOR(1550.00/12)
       END
FROM T
```

Comment: is the Select 1-12 required? as I may be including 18 month, 24 month breakdowns etc?

Comment: @Crezzer7 - You could use a permanent numbers table instead. Or just calculate the two values for regular payment and final payment and call it a day or do it in your application. I don't know anything about your existing tables or the context in which you are using this resultset.

Comment: i have added some context above for you... I have given this a go but having an issue when applying the table info into, for example replacing the 1550.00 with CustomerFinance.TotalValueOwed

Comment: worked a way out of doing this from your bottom statement, much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Let me assume you have a list of numbers.  Second, in my experience, earlier payments would be rounded *up*, with the final being less than that payment (your title is doing this "correctly"):

```
select n.n as PaymentNumber,
       (case when n.n < @NumPayments then ceiling(@Amount / @NumPayments)
             else @Amount - @NumPayments * ceiling(@Amount / @NumPayments)
        end) as MonthlyAmount
from numbers n
where n.n <= @NumPayments;
```

Of course, you can do the same thing with `FLOOR()`.  Note:  this might need some adjustment for small amounts.

EDIT:

`n.n` is just the numbers.  You can use a `CTE`.  Here is an example:

```
with numbers as (
      select 1 as n
      union all
      select n + 1
      from numbers
      where n < 20
     )
```

Comment: what are you meaning by n.n?

Comment: Monthly round up is a bad idea. Simple Example: **Take 13 USD in Total.** That leads to a payout of 2 USD per month, and in December, you need to demand 11 dollars back ;)

Comment: @SQLOTL . . . The question asks about the correct way to do this an din my experience, the last payment is typically less than the earlier payments.  Rounding to a full currency unit would not be used for small amounts.

Comment: @GordonLinoff An algorithm should be universal. My experience is: One day you fall over the exception and you have a problem. For example, this payout algorithm might be used in a budgeting database, and the amounts are split over many cost centers. Voilà: You have small amounts.

Comment: @SQLOTL . . . I repeat.  In my experience, the last payment is *less* than the preceding payments.  There are ways to make the approach "universal", but the increased complexity seems unnecessary for the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff **Of course, the total is always correct.** It only may happen that the last payment is negative. One should just know that. In financial planning applications, there are typical scenarios where a salary is split over multiple Cost Centers or Cost Objects, and then you suddenly need to deal with petty cash. Or you need to calculate and divide some small tax payments, etc.